# How to update/customize/override Magento 2 css styles

Tags: magento2, less-css

So I followed the Magento 2 Docs to create my theme for the store.

*Step 1: I have created directories*
`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/
├── web/
│ ├── css/
│ │ ├── source/ 
│ ├── fonts/
│ ├── images/
│ ├── js/`

*Step 2: Added registration.php and theme.xml fiels*
`...
├── registration.php
├── theme.xml`

**Registration.php**
`<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>',
    __DIR__
);`

**theme.xml**
`<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>New theme</title>
     <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
 </theme>`

*Step 3: Applied and configured a theme in Admin, to ex.(New theme)*

Now this is where I having a problem.
Lets say for example I want to override default css style for class .logo which is
`.logo {margin: -8px auto 25px 0;}` to `.logo {margin: 0;}`

How would i properly do that? Do I need to create `_styles.less` and stick that with updated css in to the `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/` or create `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/source/_extend.less` or there is other way?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to configure compilation of style in admin path given below

```
Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Front-end development workflow
```

change to

```
Client side less compilation
```

Then edit your theme styles module wise and other `web/css/source` (common style)

```
app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name
```

run below command to set developer mode

```
- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

and clear cache and deploy static-content

```
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got it properly right way, but I got it working.
I ended up copying and pasted *default_head_blocks.xml* from luma theme to the folder `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/`

**default_head_blocks.xml**
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
    </head>
</page>`

Then added *custom.css* file to the folder `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css`. But, now I get issues with my Varnish, I have to restart it every time I do the change in the custom.css file, otherwise it won't update the code.

Answer (score 0):

well, in my case i've created: 
 
 **app/design/frontend///web/css/source/_extend.less** file
and set backend '**compiling less client side**', an that's all, refresh the project.
 
  Do all the style changes in that file 
(only for frontend, i'm working in overriding backend...)