# How do you change the color of buttons to a custom color?

Tags: magento-2.1, less-css

I've tried to define a custom color in my custom less stylesheet in my theme css/source folder and pulling it in with _styles.less but it doesn't seem to work although it is seeing the custom text styles defined in my custom less. 
But, my custom color remains undefined when I deploy it. Do I define it in _theme.less? that didn't seem right as it appears to be for altering Magento variables that have already been defined.
Do I add it to the list in the _color.less file in my lib?

Comment: if you are using magento 2 luma theme then you will try this answer : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145320/magento-2-and-change-css-styles-in-luma-as-a-child-theme/145341#145341

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to override variable value in your custom theme `_theme.less` file as below:

```
@button__color: red;
@button__background: yellow;
```

If you did,t configure compilation then refer this [How to configure css compilation?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95420/how-to-update-customize-override-magento-2-css-styles/143973#143973)

```
- php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I want to do a custom color. Can I enter @button_color: #07baba

Comment: Yes, you can use Hex Color Code as well.

Comment: is there a file to define your custom colors so if you change the color it will change everywhere? could i add it to the color.less file or elsewhere? it is not picking it up in my custom less file although it is picking up everything else in there.

Comment: Yes, copy `_colors.less` from `lib\web\css\source\lib\variables` and add in you theme `<theme_dir>\web\css\source` and you can add custom color variable and you can override variable value in your theme `_theme.less` file as well.

Comment: hi, i did copy this file to css\source and requested it change a button color via theme.less but receive error en_US/css/email.less
variable @color-bw-blue is undefined in file var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Baby/Cool/en_US/css/source/_theme.less. Should I be pulling my new color.less file in from somewhere? not sure why it's not seeing the colors defined in the color.less file.

Comment: @DipeshRangani Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328933/57334