# How to show Hamburger icon on magento2 home page

Tags: magento2

How to show a hamburger icon  (Mobile toggle navigation menu )in magento 2 home page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you have to write css functions in your css file, to display the hamburger icon , depending on the width of your window.

Comment: which file i am add code can you tell me in

Comment: It depends on your theme.  Example: app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name  or the  web/css/source  folder in your luma theme.

Comment: have a look in this post  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95420/how-to-update-customize-override-magento-2-css-styles